How to create rich TextEditor with formatting options?
I'm trying to create a text editor similar to the one in the Notes app. The Notes app provides the following formatting options:

Text Styles: Title, Heading, Subheading, Body
Text Formatting: Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough
Colors: Highlight, Text Color
Lists: Bullet, Dash, Numbered
Alignment: Left, Right
Block Quote

I want to replicate this functionality, but I'm struggling to find a way to achieve it using the standard TextEditor in SwiftUI. Is there existing support for these features in SwiftUI that I might have overlooked?
If not, would I need to build this functionality from scratch? If so, what would be the recommended approach or any resources I could use to implement it?
Here is an example of my usage of TextEditor:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct NoteView: View {
    let note: Note
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .onAppear {
                text = note.body
            }
            .onChange(of: text) {
                note.body = text
            }
            .padding()
    }
}


Attributed String

I believe you have to build it yourself from the ground up using AttributedString objects as Lorem Ipsum says. (And beware, it's a fair bit of work. I've written a styled text editor before.)
